# Prevent attachment from being deleted

Tags: hooks, attachments, customization

In  Wordpress admin media library page (upload.php) I'd like to do some checking on delete_attachment action.

I want my custom function to fire before attachment's being deleted.

In this function I want to check for it's relations with another objects in database. And delete it only if there are no relations at all.

I use this code (in functions.php) to see if my function is fired on delete_attachment:

```
add_action( 'delete_attachment', 'check_relations' );
function check_relations( $post_id ){
    ?>  
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

but it seems that my function's not firing at all. And image attachment is being completely deleted. What's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28429009/3967385

Actually you can't fire JavaScript with php simply like that.

Comment: Actually it looks like the same question and as it is accepted over there at stackoverflow I think she saw this. Never the less, good to have a reference to the answer of this cross post. Therefore +1.